# Facebook login with Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm using Firebase Auth in my Android application, but I have a problem.

I can link my app to my Facebook from my phone and once they are linked, my Firebase user still `null`. I don't know why.

Does someone have an idea of what is happening? Below is my code.

I'm following the steps on [Firebase GitHub repo](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/minSdkJellybean/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/FacebookLoginActivity.java#L150-L156). I am using Firebase 9.0.1.

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_connexion_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            startActivity(new Intent(ConnectActivity.this,Events.class));
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            //updateUI(null);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            //updateUI(null);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    });

mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                dataIntoPref(user.getDisplayName(),String.valueOf(user.getPhotoUrl()));
                Toast.makeText(ConnectActivity.this,user.getDisplayName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(ConnectActivity.this,Events.class));
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Toast.makeText(ConnectActivity.this,"User is Null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };

 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
```

the handleFacebookAccessToken is wrotten like this:

```
AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(ConnectActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        // hideProgressDialog();
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You're missing [step 4](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login#authenticate_with_firebase), you still haven't called `mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)` to exchange the Facebook token for a Firebase one. Also, where is your code for `handleFacebookAccessToken()`? It looks like you've just copied/pasted one step of the documentation and not actually run this. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There's no possible way to help you debug a coding issue without the actual code.

Comment: @Kato i update my post. i add the handleFacebookAccessToken() to the previous code.